# How to insert sum value to another table using procedure oracle

Tags: oracle, sum, procedure

I want to make a table that contains summary value from another table; the purpose is to make a balance sheets report. I'm new in Oracle database so I'm still confused regarding how to do that. Is it using procedure, if yes so how to do it?

Here is the example data

In table 1 :

```
Year  | Periode | Date Trx | Debit | Credit
2014  |  Jan    | 2/1/2014 |    50 |     0
2014  |  Jan    | 3/1/2014 |     0 |    20
2014  |  Feb    | 2/2/2014 |     0 |   100
2014  |  Feb    | 6/2/2014 |    50 |     0
2015  |  Mar    | 2/3/2014 |     0 |    80
2015  |  Mar    | 8/3/2014 |    50 |     0
2015  |  Okt    | 2/10/2014|    50 |     0
```

And I want the result in table 2 to like this:

```
Year  | Periode | Debit | Credit
2014  |  Jan    |    50 |    20
2014  |  Feb    |    50 |   100
2015  |  Mar    |    50 |    80
2015  |  Okt    |    50 |     0
```

I hope someone could tell me how to make the procedure

Answer (score 0):

from the sample that you provided - it can be resolved 
via simple sql. it's common sql and no specific oracle features are required here

```
select year, period, sum(debit) as debit, sum(credit) as credit 
from my_table
group by year, period
```

Answer (score 0):

As @are notes a procedure is not needed here - but if you really insist on using one it would look something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE POPULATE_BALANCE_SHEET_REPORT IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TABLE2
    SELECT YEAR, PERIODE, SUM(DEBIT), SUM(CREDIT)
      FROM TABLE1
      GROUP BY YEAR, PERIODE;
END POPULATE_BALANCE_SHEET_REPORT;
```

Best of luck.